# How to format a double without converting it into string type

Tags: java, parsing, decimalformat

I want values like

```
1,
1.0,
0
```

to be formatted to

```
1.00,
1.00,
0.00
```

I'm using the following code,

```
Double stringToNumber=Double.parseDouble("3");
DecimalFormat toTheFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
toTheFormat.format(stringToNumber)
```

`.format` returns a string and if I parse using `Double.parseDouble()` method.

I lose the precision, i,e 3.00 becomes 3.0 again.How to solve this?

Comment: Define "formatted".

Comment: Hi, why would you format Double? It usually task to be done on the UI with the help of formatters.

Comment: arrange or put into a format.

Comment: Numbers are values; they don't have a format. They can be converted to strings in a particular format. But the *value* `1.00` is identical to `1.0`. Hence the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @nomadus I'm creating and writing a excel in java using jxl jar. Here I want to insert a floating point value without losing the precision. So i'm using Double.

Comment: Which library are you using to download into XLS? Is it Apache POI?

Comment: Excel has formatting.... why don't you use that?

Comment: @nomadus It isn't apache POI, i'm using JXL jar.

Comment: Excel formatting? @Vincent

Comment: Hi, does this library allow to set the cell format?

Comment: something like this....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536405/jxl-number-format-and-cell-type

Comment: Use parsefloat ()

Comment: @Vincent I'm using that only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work? I have made changes

```
    public class Tester {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double d = 1;
        NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        numFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
        numFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        System.out.println(numFormat.format(d));
    }
}
```

Comment: This will print 1.346 - fine, but if try to print 1, it should print like 1.00, but this code doesn't do so. Still thanks for the reply.

Comment: It now prints 1.00, if the number is 1.

Comment: `numFormat.format(d)` returns a string and i cannot insert number as a string, i can do it, but in excel sheet it would prompt as error.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This has to be done in JXL side where you set the format of XLS cell to numeric.

Comment: Could you try this? WritableCellFormat cf2 = new WritableCellFormat(NumberFormats.FLOAT);
    Number n = new Number(2,1,3.1415926535,cf2);
    s.addCell(n);